# Loading OBJ Models into M3G

Tags: java, java-me, 3d, .obj, m3g

I would like to start learning java 3d for mobile and I started from here: http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/objm3g/ . I'm trying to load .obj file into m3g by converting it into Java method. My question is how do I do it?
Please explain me it step by step. I didn't succeed to find ObjView after I installed Java 3d (SE) on my PC...

(I also read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wi-mobile1/ for further explanations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't succeed to find ObjView

That's because you looked in the wrong place. I found ObjView right at the page you mentioned first: http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/objm3g/

At this page,

1. go to bottom of the page and find section called **Downloads**
2. at Downloads section, find bullet saying
   [Zipped Source code and OBJ examples for M3G Chapter 1](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/objm3g/objM3G.zip) (260 KB)...
3. click above link to download file **objM3G.zip**
4. unzip the file and read instructions in ObjM3G\readme.txt
   note zip contains sub-folder *ObjView* with the source code

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcZGR.jpg]